# how can install my app which is in development mode to another user of same domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gmail-addons

I have developed a gmail addon and wanted to test the unpublished addon in another user of same domain. I created a new version deployment and tried installing.

With that id i tried installing in other account but getting this error 
**Invalid developer add-on. Please ensure the ID is correct and that your account has permission to access the add-on.**. I was thinking that i need to provide permission some where for other users to access it? Can some one help me with what change i should make so that i can add it to any user in same domain and test?

My Manifest file

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
  "userSymbol": "AdminDirectory",
  "serviceId": "admin",
  "version": "directory_v1"
   }, {
  "userSymbol": "AdminReports",
  "serviceId": "admin",
  "version": "reports_v1"
   }]
 },
  "oauthScopes": 
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",  
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
     "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
     "myDomain.com/""
   ],
  "gmail": {
        "name": "Great",
        "logoUrl": "Url",
        "contextualTriggers": [{
        "unconditional": {
        },
            "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
        }],
        "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
        "secondaryColor": "#4285F4",
        "openLinkUrlPrefixes": ["myDomain.com/"]
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you enabled the API on the second user account?

Comment: which Api? could you please explain in detail?

Comment: In your `oauthScopes` there are 3 APIs listed for your project.

Comment: Also code was there in my account only. not in any shared account /drive.

Comment: can you explain how do i enable api on second user account and make that work

Comment: To enable the API it depends on how your project is stored, if it's just on the app script dev environment you can enable them from the editor in **resources->Advanced google Services** and enable them there. Another way is from the Google Cloud Console, [here are some instructions](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en) in how to do it.